# Being + past participle form

Tags: past-participles

I was wondering to know what kind of grammar has been used in the below sentence in regards to being+ing. How should I make this kind of sentence?

> The strike led to classes being cancelled for about 500,000 of Oklahoma's 700,000 public school students.

Comment: There is no "being + ing" in that sentence. Do you mean, "being + ed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a prepostional phrase "to classes being cancelled" and the object of the preposition is a participle phrase, headed by the participle "being". The word "classes" is the subject of that participle and "cancelled" is the complement.  The word cancelled is a passive participle.

This isn't a special pattern to learn, its just building up a clause from lots of simple blocks.  The verb "led" has a prepositional phrase as its complement.  The prepositional phrase has a gerund/participle as its object  The gerund participle has a subject, and a verb in the passive voice.